# Adding edges among concept tikz library mindmap, background

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new in posting on stack.exchange but I use LaTeX since few years and I find it really helpful for producing high quality documents.

I am writing my phd thesis in LaTeX and I am creating a graph using tikz, libraries mindmap and backgrounds, and it looks perfect, exactly as I have it in mind. The original code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikz [mindmap, every node/.style=concept, concept color=black!20,grow cyclic,
level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=61},
level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=60}]
\node [root concept] { \LARGE Root Concept}
child { node [concept] (A) {A}
child { node {child} }
child { node {child} }
}
child { node [concept] (B) {B}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (C) {C}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (D) {D}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (E) {E}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (F) {F}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
};
\end{document}
```

Than, I try to add some connection among A, B, C, D, E and F (than F with A) and things get complicated! I would like to produce a ring connecting the 2nd level nodes among them, but my code ends up in messing all the original structure! Here my trial:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds}
\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, every node/.style=concept, concept color=black!20,grow cyclic,
level 1/.append style={level distance=1cm,sibling angle=61},
level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=60}]
\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=lightgray, text=black, grow cyclic]
\node [root concept] { \LARGE Root Concept}
child { node [concept] (A) {A}
child { node {child} }
child { node {child} }
}
child { node [concept] (B) {B}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (C) {C}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (D) {D}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (E) {E}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
}
child { node [concept] (F) {F}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
child { node {child}}
};
\end{scope}

\draw [concept connection] (A) edge (B)
                                         (B) edge (C)
                                         (C) edge (D)
                                         (D) edge (E)
                                         (E) edge (F)
                                     (F) edge (A);                                   

 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I cannot figure out how to perform this task. Than I would like also use the background library to add further connections among the second level nodes, let's say A and C.

I would really appriciate any help in this direction!  Thanks, E.

Comment: Your second code (with `\end{document` added at the end) seems to be working. Could you please edit your question with a picture of what you currently have and what you want?

Comment: Ok, running the sample code I created actually works, I realized that I might need to reduce the lenght of the words I am using in the nodes. Ahahah such a nice debut on the forum -.-'' Thanks! for the comment!

Comment: Well I found the murderess: I added this in my original graph with connections right after the main node [clockwise from=0] and it was this piece of code that actually messed up everything. Sorry for the waste of time :)